# Apache dying when new domain is added/removed

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, proxy, httpd

Each time I add new domain inside my server's control panel the Apache server and nginx as frontend proxy should restart - nginx as reload, apache as graceful.

However it throws nginx error page, then everything is dying (no such page found) so nginx goes down too, then all services are starting again and everything is working fine till next domain is added/removed.

Why it's showing No such file or directory ?

```
[Mon Sep 15 00:48:55 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.6 mod_rpaf/0.6 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 15 00:49:39 2014] [error] child process 22371 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Mon Sep 15 00:50:06 2014] [alert] (2)No such file or directory: FastCGI: read() from pipe failed (0)
[Mon Sep 15 00:50:06 2014] [alert] (2)No such file or directory: FastCGI: the PM is shutting down, Apache seems to have disappeared - bye
[Mon Sep 15 00:50:10 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

Another tests:

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and

```
httpd -t
Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1):

The "No such file or directory" could be a reference to a non-existent module in the Apache configuration. The configuration won't say that it's missing, and pass it as OK to you, however the server won't start because the module is still non-existent. I would say look at plugins that use FastCGI as a wrapper (like PHP, which this problem occurred with me on) and disable them, re-enabling one by one until you find the error again. Sometimes this error will occur because your server is looking for an extension in the server path, and the extension is somewhere else (hence, no such file or directory).

Comment: Except that in this case it complains about the FastCGI socket. One process above its getting a SIGKILL, so it is very likely in the FastCGI configuration.

Comment: Here's my config: http://pastebin.com/GYBnhQBc